# Difference between "ease" and "easy"

Tags: differences

I want to know the difference between *ease* and *easy*. Please give me some examples of places to use these words.

Answer (score 9):

The biggest difference is that "ease" is a noun and a verb, and "easy" is an adjective.

Roughly speaking: the opposite of *difficult* is *easy*, and the opposite of *difficulty* is *ease* (but only in the uncountable sense - you can talk about the difficulty/ease of a task, and coming across "a difficulty", but not "*an ease").

*To ease* something into somewhere means to put it in slowly and gradually - the opposite of forcing it in.  Examples:

> The first question is very easy.
>
> I answered the first question with ease.
>
> The ease of communicating by email makes it very popular.
>
> I eased my foot into the tight-fitting shoe.

Comment: Interesting… the opposite of the word that ends in *y* doesn't, and vice-versa. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. Now I am feeling ease with the process of upgrading my english skills.

Comment: A somewhat slanderous term, you can use 'easy' to describe a girl who readily consents to sexual intercourse with a variety of men.  This is not a term that should be used in polite company.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Nice observation - I didn't even notice that :)

Comment: @A.C.Balaji: Pleased to hear it :) A nice idiom is that we usually say we're feeling "at ease" with something if we're relaxed / comfortable with it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ease - basically means comfort or pleasing
Easy - refers to mostly the load of an action being performed, kind of "not difficult". needs less efforts to complete it

Comment: I think you are failing to capture the essential difference (which psmears did) which is that they are difference parts of speech. "Ease" can mean "comfort", but it cannot mean "pleasing" (in the sense I think you intend) because "pleasing" in that sense is an adjective, and "ease" can never be that.